# Flutter: Riverpod change value using methods

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to learn how to use riverpod for state management in a Flutter app. I'm building a simple counter app and I have done the following:

My provider:

```
@riverpod
class Counter extends _$Counter {
  int _value = 0;

  @override
  int build() => _value;

  void increment() {
    print("incrementing");
    _value++;
  }
}
```

In my `ConsumerWidget` build method I'm obtaining the following:

```
final counterValue = ref.watch(counterProvider);
final counter = ref.read(counterProvider.notifier);
```

I present the value in a Text widget in the following manner:

```
Text(counterValue.toString())
```

And my button action is the following:

```
onPressed: () {
    counter.increment();
}
```

In my console I see it's printing "incrementing" meaning that my method is called. But the value on screen doesn't seem to change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing a property of the notifier.  The notifier emits only when its state is updated.  If your incrementor was updating with `state++`, it would work, and you wouldn't need the `_value` property at all.

Comment: What do I do if what I return is a more complex object with properties and I do keep a local variable with that object, and I change one of the properties, how do I make the state to refresh?

Comment: in that case you have a (preferably immutable) single object for state.